# Joomla 2.5: Center-alignment for four(4) custom html-boxes in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla2.5

Currently, I'm trying to center-align four(4) custom html-boxes I've made in Joomla 2.5.x., with the ability to center themselfs after one or more of the boxes is unpublished.

So far, I've tried to make a "div"(with a class) inside an article, where I loaded each of the four(4) custom html-boxes with {loadposition name}. But when I do that, the boxes gets centered under each other in the middle of the page.

In the following example, this is what I would like to get Joomla to do:
I've made five(5) boxes, each in custom html. Then loaded them into one article with the following method:    `qB48w`[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qB48w/). Here, when one uncomments a box, the rest of boxes get automatically centered.

With the example above, I would like to be able to do the same with 4 boxes, all of them made in custom-html in Joomla 2.5.x

Can anyone help me with this challenge, or point me in the right direction ?

Best regard
Jens.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` elements are block-level elements. That means that, unless you tell them otherwise, they will occupy 100% the width of their parent element.

It sounds like you are loading 4 custom_html modules, which are all 100% wide, which each have their contents centered.

The solution is to force them to the width of their content only by specifying your own custom css, e.g.

```
.module-centered {display: inline-block; text-align: center;}
```

Then, to make this apply to each module, set the module class (in the modules advanced settings) to `module-centered` (note the preceding space).